# Saving nested model laravel in one go

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have create two tables

```
AREAS
-id
-areaName

SOCIETIES
-id
-area_id
-societyName
```

My relationship is defined like this

```
class Area extends Model
{
    //
    public function society()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Society');
    }
}

class Society extends Model
{
    public function area()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Area');
    }
}
```

Now I have created objects for both area and society

```
$area = new \App\Area();
$area->areaName = $input['areaName'];

$society = new \App\Society();
$society->societyName = $input['societyName'];

$society->area()->associate($area);
```

After this when I call "$society->save()" its not saving any record and giving error area_id cannot be null. I want to save society and its relation area in one go.

When I use "$area->save()" before associate its saving the record when calling "$society->save()". All I want to do is skip "$area->save()" and save both society and area in one go.

Comment: Did you try `$area->society()->save($society)`;? That should achieve what you want.

Comment: same exception "area_id" cannot be null

Comment: After associate society object return this now I want to save whole object in one go
{
  "societyName": "qqqq",
  "area_id": null,
  "area": {
    "areaName": "ddddd"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

It is giving you the error because you don't have a record in the database with an id for it. You need to save the area record first and then associate it with the relation. I don't think it will work other wise, take a look at eloquent docs on laravel's website:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships